# Why findViewById of HierarchyViewer is so painfully slow?

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

It takes 5-6 seconds to find some UI control (as example a button).

Two questions:

1) Why is it so slow?

2) Is there a way to make it faster or some alternative solution for finding UI control (in scope of monkeyrunner testing)

Comment: HierarchyViewer is not intended to be used as a testing tool. It's only purpose is to capture the entire view hierarchy for debugging. Its protocol is private and can change at any time so you should not rely on it.

Comment: 2Roman: What are the other options? Blackbox automated testing (as example monkey runner) requires checking the UI state of an application .

Comment: As of 4.1 you can use the new Accessibility APIs.

Comment: As of 4.2 you can use the new UI automation testing framework. See the SDK release notes for more information at http://d.android.com

Comment: 2Romain: Thank you. I saw press release. I definitely have to try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked into Android source code a little bit and found that when you search for a control using findViewById in monkeyrunner, it actually iterates through all controls on all running windows in Android.

So, if you have some Activity which is paused (and not visible), by not destroyed, findViewById will spend time searching through it.

I have several ideas for now

a) Use getFocusedWindowName API on HierarhyViewer to check that correct window is displayed.
Try to search this window first and after specify it as parent in findViewById(id, parent) method. This way, we won't search through all windows on Android.

2) Try to bypass interface provided by com.android.chimpchat.hierarchyviewer.HierarchyViewer and go directly to DeviceBridge class (which provides a little bit lower level for the same protocol). In such case, instead of acquiring all controls for all windows, we can precisely point which window should be searched.

As Romain pointed out. HierarchyViewer may change in the future. However, I don't see any other replacement for this, as part of testing automation.

Answer (score 1):

Usually it's sufficient to find the control just once and store it in a field.

In case of an adapter view they usually store all references to its children views in an object, then attach that object to the view using setTag(). Later it can be retrieved for the same view with getTag(). You can search the net for the ViewHolder example to see this technique

I doubt though it takes 5-6 sec maybe you have so very many controls..

Comment: 5-6 is real value. I added my own answer below. The issue is that even finding a control once takes 5-6 seconds. So, caching (i.e. saving the control in a field) won't help.

Answer (score 0):

[AndroidViewClient](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient), while not faster because it relies on the same protocol as HierarchyViewer, may provide a simpler alternative to write tests.

Take a look at the [examples](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/tree/master/AndroidViewClient/examples). There are also cases where AndroidViewClient provides workarounds for know monkeyrunner bugs (see this [example](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/blob/master/AndroidViewClient/examples/monkeyrunner-issue-36544-workaround.py))